# Why exceptions are thrown by format() function instead of compile time error?

Tags: java, formatting

For example i have the following code

```
class Format{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String formated = String.format( "%c",-42); //I have -42 as second argument.
    System.out.println(formated);
  }
}
```

I know this is very bad as it throws IllegalFormatCodePointException but question that struck to my mind is that why compiler is not complaining here,if it can complain at

```
char c = -42;
```

So,knowing that the upper code produces an exception,Why compiler just sit and watch?

Comment: Because the compiler isn't written to verify that the arguments you're passing into methods are correct, as it has no clue what the programmer wants the method to do. It just verifies types.

Comment: @user3580294 then what about char c = -42; now compiler checks the value also?

Comment: I don't think any other language implementing `printf` even tries to statically check that.

Comment: I divided a number by 0, compiler did not complain..

Comment: @Bayant_singh Because that's a type check, not a correctness check. You can't assign an `int` to a `char` without an explicit cast.

Comment: @user3580294 SO why type check is not there in format()?

Comment: Look at the prototype of the method : `public static String format(String format, Object... args)`. That's what the compiler can check.

Comment: It is. You're passing in `String` arguments, which the method is declared to accept. The type check is there.

Comment: @dystroy you have a point...

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a code contract-like feature. Such a thing is *significantly* more difficult to implement generally as you start running into some computer theory barriers.

Comment: @user3580294 please provide some source if you have about it.

Comment: @Bayant_singh Something like [this](https://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/). There's still research going on about it, but take a look. I don't know much about them because I haven't used them, but I've heard about them and they sound vaguely like what you were expecting.

Comment: @user3580294 it seems to me as static checking?

Comment: @Bayant_singh Something like that, except with code contracts you can inspect the values of arguments in addition to their types.

Comment: @user3580294 and that inspection is at compile time.

Comment: @Bayant_singh I think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no facility at the language level to define this type of constraint.

What the compiler can check is that the type of the arguments is the one defined by [the method prototype](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) :

```
public static String format(String format, Object... args)
```

You can see it's extremely dynamic and that you can pass sometimes an int, and sometimes somethings's else, which can be convenient, especially as some [format strings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) are able to handle for various types. The format string itself could also be dynamically provided.

I don't know any language implementing `printf` and able to statically check that. It's such a specific feature that it's always implemented *using* the language, not at the language definition level.

Comment: So the second argument is using "autoboxing" ..but the statement char c = -42;is still a hurdle in my understanding that if compiler checks only type then how it produces error for this?

Comment: @Bayant_singh Because `c` is a `char`, and `-42` is an `int`, and you can't assign an `int` directly to a `char` variable.

Comment: @user3580294 oh! sir i can do char c = 42; i have checked but -42 is producing error.please check.

Comment: @Bayant_singh Because your compiler is smart enough to see that `42` is in the range of a char and can figure out the conversion implicitly. See what happens if you try `12345678`, which clearly is out of range for a `char`.

Comment: @dystroy So in the case of argument matching compiler only sees if the parameters can hold the arguments

Answer (score 2):

> So, knowing that the upper code produces an exception.  Why compiler does just sit and watch?

Because the Java Language Specification says it should.

The type signature for the `format` method is `format(String format, Object... args)`, and the JLS says that the if the arguments conform to that signature after application of prescribed conversions then the code is valid.  The compiler is **NOT ALLOWED** to say "compilation error" for your code ... because the code is valid Java code.

---

In fact, the only way that the compiler *could* "know" that the your code will always produce an exception is if it is coded with special knowledge of what format strings mean.  And, in that case, the most that a (hypothetical) compiler with that special knowledge would be *allowed* to do would be to output a Warning.

In reality, this kind of thing is treated as beyond the scope of a typical compiler.  Rather it is the problem domain of static analysis tools such as FindBugs and PMD.  (Or for the C language, the Lint tool ... which IIRC does check format strings in some versions.)